# CompositeConfiguration - property with same name

Tags: java, apache-commons

I search proper way to use composite configuration with multiple config files with same property names. So i have configuration files with some prefixes foo_AA, foo_BB, foo_CC and foo* configuration files have same context (property names, xml arch) and if using [CompositeConfiguration](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration/CompositeConfiguration.html) we have problem with same names.

For me obvisous way using filename prefix before propery.

```
CompositeConfiguration conf;
conf.addConfiguration(new XMLConfiguration("foo_AA.xml));
conf.addConfiguration(new XMLConfiguration("foo_BB.xml));
conf.getProperty("foo_AA.xml.some_property");
```

So, i newbie in java so i don't know possibilities and may be it's already done? Or may be another way exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `CompositeConfiguration`, you can use `MapConfiguration`, [here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration/MapConfiguration.html) is the javadoc.

The basic idea is to read all `XMLConfiguration`, and add all properties into the `MapConfiguration` with file name prefix key.

Comment: Thanks! It's exactly that i search.